# LM2678 Switching Regulator Voltage Dropout Under Load and extreme Input Distortion

Tags: power-supply, switching-regulator

I recently had a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498064/lm2678-pcb-layout-question-review) about the layout for an LM2678-ADJ switching regulator.
Since, I have built the circuit and layout as follows:

[image]
[image]

So far, I have only had moderate success with the circuit.
With an input voltage of 30V and up to 6A available, everything works well (at least, output voltage constant), up to a current draw of up to about 2.5A.
**Above that, the voltage drops dramatically and the diode starts getting hot(ter)**.

The following waveforms were taken at different current draws, with the rheostat set to produce 12V out:
**Yellow** is measured across diode D1, and **blue** across capacitor C3 at the output on the right.

---

**Current Draw: 0.1A**

[image: a]

---

**Current Draw: 2.4A**

[image]

---

**Current Draw: 2.5A**

[image]

---

**Current Draw: 3.0A**

[image]

Aside from the slight ringing at 0.1A, it seems to normalize out to a square waveform by about 0.15A and everything looks well to about 2.4A.

However, at around 2.5A, where the voltage drop occurs, there seem to be "misses" in the waveform, and going further in 0.1A increments to 3.0A, the waveform only shows "misses".

I have read on [other threads](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180554/switching-regulator-ti-lm2678-not-working-on-load-100ma) that the inductor needs to be large and have low resistance.

**L1 is a torodial  47 µH with a DCR max = 13.5 mΩ and rated 10A**.

**D1 is an STPSC10H065D 10A Schottky Diode**

I have tried a small ceramic across D1's terminals without success.
Also, [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149386/lm2678-output-voltage-drop-under-load) says ringing should be checked, but there doesn't seem to be any in the above output (except under low/no load conditions).

**So finally, my question is very basic: What is causing this, and how can it be fixed?**

The datasheets for the components are here:

[L1 Datasheet](https://www.reichelt.de/index.html?ACTION=7&LA=3&OPEN=0&INDEX=0&FILENAME=B400%2FTLC10A.pdf)

[D1 Datasheet](https://www.reichelt.de/index.html?ACTION=7&LA=3&OPEN=0&INDEX=0&FILENAME=A400%2FSTPSC10H065D.pdf)

[Regulator Datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjglJrMqbjpAhUD7KYKHavEAPwQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Flm2678.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0rCQrJu71xaQNyHnZWhnls)

**EDIT 2020-05-22**

I have measured the input voltage, and am seeing some nasty feedback/ringing that I think is causing my issue:
The blue is the input measured across Input and GND pins on the regulator (AC coupling), and yellow measured on Switch_Output pin (DC coupling)

**0.2A load**
[image]

**2.0A load; distortion worse**
[image]

**3.0A load; everything is crazy**
[image]

I have tried:

- Adding more input capacitance (to lower RMS)
- Adding more output capacitance (to lower RMS)
- Trying different Schottky diode
- Different inductors as suggested and accepted as answer at first, one 3A 47uH for 255kHz switching regulators, and a 68uH stolen from a DC-DC boost converter. There was no measurable effect.
- Resoldering on another prototype board with different layout in case ground plane or whatever on the board is causing this. Effect was about 0.3A more load before breakdown.

Comment: Schematic and part numbers plus data sheet links are usually the most important things to post first.

Comment: The waveform for the low load is identical to the discontinuous mode (which is to be expected) switching diagram in the datasheet; see figure 13.

Comment: @Andyaka Added the datasheet links and schematic from other post

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, that looks to be ok then. It's my first time trying a switching regulator. The datasheet has a lot of things in it that I am not fully familar with yet :}

Comment: The inductor data sheet you linked does not state the rated current - better link/DS is needed or don't use that part.

Comment: Although the inductor rated current appears to be part of the part number (10A), there are a couple of issues. What is not shown is the \$V \mu S\$ rating. The inductance is listed for 1kHz but not for the frequencies your circuit is seeing. The \$V \mu S\$ rating is a critical part of the design process. See pages 22 and 23 of the datasheet. From your scope captures, it *appears* it is going into current limit or becoming unstable.

Comment: @namezero The datasheet you linked to gives manucturer names and part numbers of suitable components. Could you use those?

Comment: I have doubts that the capacitors can handle this kind of high frequency ripple current. Can you provide cap datasheets?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The only suitable component would be L48, which through hole is RL-1282-47-43. I could not find this part inventoried on my normal stores, and even Digikey does not show any "Renco" inductors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM2678 operates at approximately 260 kHz and this means that you must choose an inductor with a lot of care and attention to detail. The inductor you have chosen is \$\color{red}{\text{not suitable}}\$ from the information that is available. Having dug a little deeper it seems that its core is iron dust/powder and this is likely to have significant eddy current losses at 260 kHz. What mouser says about this 47 uH: -

[image]

Highlighted in red boxes are the things that sounds alarms with me.

I'm not ruling out anything else but the inductor is a poor choice.

Comment: I have also noted that the volt microsecond rating is not stated, but it is a critical part of the design procedure.

Comment: @PeterSmith I doubt that not having this stated is the problem, it's more basic than that.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for the analysis. I never had to consider things like eddy current before; this would not have stood out to me. The recommended RL1282 cannot be found anywhere (e.g. Mouser or Digikey), but I will attempt to find an inductor that is tested at 260khz and does not have an iron core.

Comment: Choose a ferrite core material preferably made from a material that has low losses at 300 kHz. 3F3 material made by Ferroxcube springs to mind if you want to use that as a techy reference but, in truth, all the major ferrite makers have a near equivalent.

Comment: @Andyaka It was a good guess, but it seems like the inductor (at least by itself) was not at fault since I have tried now a smaller (3A, 47uH at 255khZ) with insignificant changes. I have updated the question because I suspect input distortion caused by the regulator.

Comment: @namezero Please link to the data sheet of the inductor and, if you want help, don't assume I'm automatically wrong by getting rid of the answer acceptance - my answer was correct - the inductor in question is not suitable based on the limited specifications and that it is an iron dust core. My final line in my answer above was this, just to remind you: *I'm not ruling out anything else but the inductor is a poor choice*. So, if you want help please start acting like it.

Comment: Ok apologies; I didn't mean offense. The one inductor was a SH260S-5.0-50 (https://talema.com/uploads/documents/product-datasheets/SH260%20Series.pdf) stolen from a DC-DC converter. It measured about 50uH, so I suspect it to be the 52uH model.

Comment: OK, what inductor did you choose - where is the part number. This is the starting point - always start at the inductor and prove it's good because, without a good inductor anything else is pointless.

Comment: I'm not very keen on those either - they are pretty light on performance curves such as inductance vs temperature, losses vs temperature, inductance change vs DC current, self-resonant frequency. Personally I wouldn't choose one of these but, at least you have found a part whose data sheet says it's supposedly compatible with the LM2678. On a different tack - what does the incoming power supply voltage look like when the circuit starts misbehaving?

Comment: My idea was to test a different, "more appropriate" inductor and see if it changes anything significantly. Obtaining a 5A 47uH inductor at 250khz off any major supplier seems to be impossible. I have updated my question with the curves of the incoming voltage before; I strongly suspect the problem there due to extreme distortion.

Comment: If blue is your power supply input then that's your problem - specifically where does this power rail come from?

Comment: Yes, blue is the input. I suspect the problem here. It is coming from a bench power supply; in this case set to 10V with max 10A load. I have tinkered with more input capacitance and another 100nF across the regulator input; nothing seems to calm it down.

Comment: Try something like 1000 uF - you have to stop the power rail doing this or you won't get anywhere with it. What is the bench supply part number?

Comment: Hi, I'm using a PeakTech 6181 with two channels connected in parallel. I thought it might be a problem if the supply also uses a switching regulator but dismissed the idea. I will add some more capacitance and report tonight.

Comment: OK good luck dude.

Comment: Mh well I tried more input capacitance and powering it from a transformer with rectifier to exclude the power supply with the same result. Adding a second diode in parallel increased the ringing slightly, so today I will try a completely different, isolated diode in case somehow the unisolated tab is causing too much EMF or something...

Comment: I'm just looking at D1 diode - it has a lot of capacitance for what it does and it also has a lot of forward volt drop for a schottky too. What made you choose that type and did you consider any alternatives. My turn to is a 1N5804 but it's not got the current rating. The 6TQ045 looks a better choice - much lower volt drop and capacitance is much less too.

Comment: Well, the reason was that I had this diode and it was a Schottky with an appropriate rating according to the datasheet. I now used (one side of) a MBR30200 (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj8o_K7-svpAhUvNOwKHdGmAt8QFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdatasheet.lcsc.com%2Fszlcsc%2F1903111002_Chongqing-Pingwei-Tech-MBR3045CT_C360501.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2pCqHL6S1e_LNbWSQHkAaU) that seems to works up to about 4.5A, although the input distortion is not something that seems to be possible to get rid of.

Comment: Same as with inductors, TI recommends parts that are vaporware (not listed on many suppliers, can only be purchased in quantities of "lots", etc) so really you have to go with your own.

Comment: OK it was failing at 3 amps and is now failing at 4.5 amps?

Comment: Yes, the diode change increased the breakdown current from ~2.5A to ~4.5A. Above that unfortunately I think I killed a regulator when the input breaks down like crazy :D. I will try replacing the damaged regulator and maybe adding the seconds part of the diode in parallel.

Comment: I still have suspicions about the power supply.

Comment: I tried using a transformer with a bridge rectifier to exclude the power supply from the circuit and it didn't seem to make a difference with the input ringing :/ In what way would you suspect it?

Comment: If it's a decent power supply it should be able to supply the current without going crazy on its output voltage. Have you considered using a car lead acid battery at 12 volts to see what happens?

Comment: I will repair later and try with some UPS lead-acid batteries and report back. This guy (https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/t/331046?I-can-not-operate-at-higher-currents-the-LM2678) had a similar problem where Vin voltage spikes were suspected but the issue went unresolved. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you get the LM2678 from a reputable source?

Comment: I would say yes; from reichelt.com .

Comment: Try lowering the power supply to 24 volts and see what happens.

Comment: The 4.5A test was only with 10V input to 5V output. At 30V amperage was the same, only the regulator blew up. This certainly is one of the more frustrating projects I've had lol.

Comment: Try replacing the pot resistor (possible inductive coupling) with a fixed value type. A 3k3 resistor will do for 5.2 volts output.

Comment: Also, how hot does the inductor get at say a 3 amp output with the input supply being stable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108418/discussion-between-namezero-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Ok, I have resoldered with the new regulator onto the initial board. Together with the MBR30200 diode I can actually draw 5.1A from the output with 30V in from the power supply. The ringing is still there with almost 2V, so very bad. A 24V input from a pair of lead-acid batteries deteriorated the situation at 4.5A so that the input would get crazy again (the regulator hisses then). The pot is there because in the final installation there is supposed to be a front panel knob to adjust the voltage from 5-24V output. The inductor does not warm up to the touch. Only regulator and diode get "hot".

Comment: Try replacing the pot with a fixed resistor because it will pick up noise. Just as an experiment. I am worried if the pot you plan to use is on long leads. It’s a very critical part in the feedback loop and is sensitive.

Comment: I will replace the pot for testing and report :} If that's the problem I will figure out some way to isolate it to create the reference voltage then.

Comment: Good luck @namezero

Comment: Mhh for what it's worth neither a fixed resistor nor connecting the future pot with a "long" cable make any difference (even if provoked by routing next to e.g. inductor for example).Since the diode made such a big difference, I sourced an "approved" diode and am waiting for the arrival.

Comment: OK, sometimes you gotta go down a few paths to get to the solution. I've learnt from the past that if the supplier specifies this or that then it's just not worth trying to find an alternative. The problem with the diode is that it had a really quite large forward volt drop.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you very much for your help. I inadvertently stumbled on the root cause and wrote it up on here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109122/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-lm2678-switching-regulator-voltage-dropout-unde).

Answer (score 1):

I will leave the original answer intact, but would like to add something about the root cause.

After despairing in many troubleshooting sessions and trying different inductors, diodes, capacitors (including components in the TI datasheet) and a different layout on prototyping board I have finally found the root cause, and can mitigate for issue.

During troubleshooting, I inadvertently measured the ringing against GND rather than VIN.
When I realized that the ringing occurred between the GND input terminal and the GND pin on the LM2678 as well as the diode, and virtually any other point on the board I measured, I tried to track down the EMF source.

It seems like the GND plane under the inductor was exposed to enough EMF to cause this issue. 
After cutting the ground under the inductor to disconnect it, the ringing stayed roughly constant:

[image]

- VIN = 10V; VOUT=5V; Input Ripple = 300mv
- VIN = 30V; VOUT=5V; Input Ripple = 500mv
- VIN = 40V; VOUT=5V; Input Ripple = 700mv

While I'm not entirely happy with (and unsure of how to improve) the 700mv at 40V in, everything runs stable at maximum current of 5A.

Comment: Oops yeah. You need to remove ground underneath any of the inductor turns that are close to the surface of the PCB. Very large eddy currents will be induced in copper close to those turns. Glad you found it; I was beginning to suspect fake components.

Comment: I'll try to move the inductor away from power planes in real life!

Comment: So maybe the rest is induced via ground on the heatsink or diode. I'll attempt to shield this somehow. Thanks for all your patience!

Comment: It'll be screwing with the inductor that's for sure.